Configure one specific path to be different in tsconfig json paths
I am working with a tsconfig json file as follows:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@filesOne/*": ["../../filesOne/*/src"],
      "@filesTwo/*": ["../../filesTwo/*/src"]
    }
  }
}

However, there is one import statement I am using in the project called @filesTwo/environments where I need the path to resolve to ../../environments/*/src instead of ../../filesTwo/*/src. Does anyone know the cleanest way to configure this within the json?
I have tried adding lines like "@filesTwo/environments": ["../../environments/*/src"] within paths hoping to overwrite "@filesTwo/*": ["../../filesTwo/*/src"] but I still get errors saying Plugin "esbuild-ts-paths" returned a non-absolute path: @filesTwo/environments (set a namespace if this is not a file path)

More specific path aliases should be placed before more general ones. In your case, it should look like this:
"paths": {
  "@filesTwo/environments/*": ["../../environments/*/src"], //Specific path
  "@filesTwo/*": ["../../filesTwo/*/src"], //General path
  "@filesOne/*": ["../../filesOne/*/src"],
  ...
}

